# PHP Mail: Sending ÅÄÖ characters?

Tags: php, email, character-encoding

I'm trying to send a mail containing ÅÄÖ characters (Swedish).

I've tried changing the mail header to UTF-8 and iso-8859-1, none of which works. I've also tried wrapping the text in utf8_encode() as well as mb_encode_mimeheader(), with no success. In some cases i get chinese characters instead, not really what i want.

I just tried using htmlentities() with no result.

```
        $values = array(
            'name' => $this->input->post('name'),
            'email' => $this->input->post('email'),
            'ref' => $this->input->post('ref'),
            'sex' => $this->input->post('sex'),
            'age' => $this->input->post('age'),
            'question' => $this->input->post('msg'),
            'ip' => $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']
        );

        $to      = '@live.se';
        $subject = $values['name'] . ' har skickat en fråga!';
        $message  = 'Namn:'.$values['name']." \r\n";
        $message .= "\r\nEmail:".$values['email']." \r\n";
        $message .= "\r\nKön:".(($values['sex'] == 'f') ? 'Kvinna' : 'Man')." \r\n";
        $message .= "\r\nÅlder:".$values['age']." \r\n";
        $message .= "\r\nReferensnummer:".$values['ref']." \r\n";
        $message .= "\r\nMeddelande: \r\n".$values['question'];

        $headers = 'From: noreply@.se' . "\r\n" .
            'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n" .
            'Reply-To: ' .$this->input->post('email') . "\r\n" .
            'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

        $message = htmlentities($message);

        if(@mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers)) {
            if($this->input->is_ajax_request()) {
                echo 1;
            }else {

                $data['message']['header'] = 'Tack så mycket!';
                $data['message']['content'] = 'Din fråga skickades utan problem! Jag återkommer snarast möjligt.';

                echo $this->load->view('includes/header', array(), true);
                echo $this->load->view('message', $data['message'], true);
                echo $this->load->view('includes/footer', array(), true);
            }
        }else {
            $fail = true;
        }
```

Comment: How are you getting the data you are trying to send in the message? From a file? DB?

Comment: Do you have the correct charset / encoding specified in the html page you are getting POST data from?

Comment: The charset is in the header, e.g. "<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8;" />", if there's none, it's definitely time to put it there... I remember having had the same problem and setting both (meta & mailheader) to iso-8859-1 worked for me! Additional note: I couldn't find a way to have those characters (german umlaute) in the sender or receiver field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A very old thread, but did not seem to have a good answer. If the encoding of the page which contains the form is encoded as utf-8, then the function `utf8_decode("your åäö-text");` is your friend.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know if this is the best way to achieve this. But I used to use mail like this:

```
mail($to, "=?utf-8?B?".base64_encode($subject)."?=", $message, $headers);
```

Answer (score 0):

While trying to figure this out, i remembered i was using Codeigniter, and thought maybe, just maybe, codeigniter had a built in Email library. And, it turns out it does!

So i gave it a shot, and found out it had a serious bug in it. Luckily, i found a fixed version of the file here: http://codeigniter.com/forums/viewthread/87108/P15/#753867

And now it works. I don't know exactly what codeigniter does to make it work, but i'm glad it does!

tl;dr: i don't have a real solution to the problem.

Comment: They appear to use q encoding, i.e. what Eliasdx suggests. You can check out their solution in system/libraries/Email.php, the function's name is _prep_q_encoding.

Answer (score -4):

This.

```
  $message = preg_replace('/[^(\x20-\x7F)]*/','', $message);
```

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but this would remove the characters entirely, no?

Comment: this would clean the message by removing all of the unnecessary special characters. e.i, ÅÄÖ.

Comment: But the characters *aren't* unnecessary in Swedish, which is why the OP would like to send them in an e-mail.